# Why do Ineed to declare a pointer and not an object?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, reference, mfc

I am using a `CMapStringToOb` to store a `CMapStringToString`

I can make this work if i declare `columns` as `*columns` but want to know why I can't get this way to work

```
CMapStringToOb m_FfMasters;
CMapStringToString columns;
// if we haven't met this master before store the details for later use
if(!m_FfMasters.Lookup(_T("String"),(CObject*&)columns) )
{

    getColumns(_T("String"),columns);

    m_FfMasters.SetAt(_T("String"),(CObject*&)columns);
    if(m_FfMasters.Lookup(m_workingFfMaster,(CObject*&)columns))
    {
        CString temp;
        if(columns.Lookup(_T("String"),temp)) //<-- access violation here
        {
            return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

the other function prototypes are:

```
void CClass::getColumns(CString code, 
                        CMapStringToString& columns, 
                        BOOL reverseKeyValue);
```

I get an access violation at the columns lookup

Comment: `columns = new CMapStringToString();` What's this?

Comment: `new` returns a pointer.

Comment: sorry this is a confused and confusing question, how do i close it?

Answer (score 2):

Because you're assigning a pointer to `columns` here:

```
columns = new CMapStringToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are asking why your compiler requires a pointer then use Paul's answer. If You are asking why a pointer *should*  be used ( you don't completely understand pointers) then the answer is: 
 Because you are writing a function that uses an object that does not yet exist as a parameter in your `CClass` class definition, `CMapStringToString columns` will not be created until run-time. So in order for the function to use this object you have to say use "this"(a reference) `CMapStringToString` object that i will give you later. then use the -> operator to access the referenced objects members.

Comment: I am asking: why does it require pointers. I admit to not fully understanding pointers. i last used them 6 years ago in basic ansi C, then moved to java now trying to maintain old c++ code

Comment: what function does this block return temp to?

Answer (score 0):

Because CMapStringToOb requires a pointer to a CObject as its "data".

from MSDN:

CMapStringToOb is a dictionary collection class that maps unique CString objects to CObject **pointers**